# ReCaptchaV2 g is undefined

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I've an error since today in my website with recaptchaV2 from Google, I've an js error `TypeError: g is undefined` from `recaptcha__fr.js file`.
I used this captcha in Joomla form aicontactsafe

Everything has been working well since 1 or 2 years and I did not change anything.
I don't understand why I have this error, I included `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` and I called captcha whith `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mootools?

It looks like there is an issue with the Google Library and Mootools as mentioned here - https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/374

I have a legacy site that started having issues at the end of last week (24th April). It might be that an upgrade for MooTools is needed

Comment: Yes I use Mootools, thank for your answer? I'll check that @Rob Wilson